# curl with --user option in nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl

I can grab a webpage in nodejs, but I need to authenticate myself first. In curl you can do this with `curl --user user:password [url]`.

How can I achieve the same results in node?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to add an authorization header to your HTTP request. The `Authorization` header should contain the username and password combined with a colon, which should then be Base64 encoded, then prepended with `Basic` and a single space.

```
var header = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');
```

Here's a complete example involving a GET request.

```
var http = require('http');

var user = 'username';
var pass = 'password';

var auth = new Buffer(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');
var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/path',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth
  }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  // response is here
});
```

Comment: Buffer is deprecated, wich else can I may use?